# Records.mapping in Kotlin

Tags: jooq

Is it possible to use `Records.mapping` in Kotlin?

The following code does work in Java, but not in Kotlin. I now also make use of `jooq-kotlin` but it doesn't seem to have an extension for `Record.mapping`.

```java
    return jooq()
        .select(ar.ID, ar.FILE_NAME, ar.FILE_PATH, ar.FILE_SIZE)
        .from(ar)
        .join(afgsar)
        .on(afgsar.ATTACHMENT_REFERENCE_ID.eq(ar.ID))
        .where(afgsar.ADVANCE_FORM_GENERIC_SECTION_ID.eq(orgId))
        .fetch(Records.mapping(AttachmentReferenceFormDto::new));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the kotlin constructor reference syntax `::Type` instead of the Java one (`Type::new`):

```kotlin
.fetch(Records.mapping(::AttachmentReferenceFormDto));
```